# render a react component that is stored in a list

Tags: reactjs

It's a bit difficult to explain my problem but I will try to explain what I'm trying to do and what is not working.

I want to render a specific component based on a prop value in my parent component. That specific component is stored in a list that I have access to.

This is ListOfComponents:

```
let React = require('react');

//List of all components
let Component1 = require("./Component1");
let Component2 = require("./folder2/Component2");
let Component3 = require("./folder2/Component3");


let ListOfComponents = {
    "id1" : {"handler":Component1},
    "id2" : {"handler":Component2},
    "id3" : {"handler":Component3},
};

module.exports = ListOfComponents;
```

And this is my parent component that want to render the different components:

```
let React = require('react');
let ListOfComponents = require('./ListOfComponents');

let ParentComponent = React.createClass({

    render() {
        let component = ListOfComponents[{this.props.compID}].handler;
        return ( component )
    }
});

module.exports = ParentComponent;
```

When I try to run this I get the error message: `Invariant Violation: ParentComponent.render() A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Can this be accomplished or do I need a different approach to render the correct component based on my ListOfComponents?

Comment: Did you try `return <component />` instead?

Comment: have you tried David suggestion

Comment: I tried it earlier and did not notice that the error in the console disappeard, I only checked the view which showed the same result so I assumed it was the same error :S 
So the correct solution is as you wrote `return <Component />` but the first letter must be capital, no idea why but it does not render the correct component otherwise. Don't know if there is any conflict with some other component maybe

Comment: What happens if you remove the `{}` from `let component = ...`, i.e. `let component = ListOfComponents[this.props.compID].handler`? This should return a proper React component, as far as I can see.

Comment: @MattSchofield I tried by writing the id directly e.g. ListOfComponents["id1"].handler and it did return a react component which I did see in console.log(component) but It was just not rendering it.

Comment: @VatanBytyqi You are right, JSX is case sensitive when it comes to xml markup for components. `component` in lowercase will render a `<component>` HTML tag, but `Component` should render the component.

Comment: @VatanBytyqi what happens if you change your render method to `return ( <div>{component}</div>`? Also, if you inspect the values of `this.props.compID` and `component` before you render, what are the values?

Comment: @MattSchofield it doesn't render anything, only the div tags. And I will not be able to send any props to my component with that kind of solution?
The solution suggested by David does work.

Answer (score 0):

Given an object with this structure:

```
let ListOfComponents = {
    "id1" : {"handler":Component1},
    "id2" : {"handler":Component2},
    "id3" : {"handler":Component3},
};
```

To dynamically render one of those components in another component's render method:

```
render() {
    const Component = ListOfComponents[this.props.compID].handler;
    return <Component />
}
```

Here's a runnable example:

```
import React from "react"

const Component1 = () => <p>Hello</p>
const Component2 = () => <p>Goodbye</p>

const components = {
  id1: Component1,
  id2: Component2,
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const id = "id2"
    const Component = components[id]
    return <Component />
  }
}

export default App
```